# Error in magento checkout page trying to skip shipment and payment methods

Tags: javascript, magento

i am trying to skip "shipping and payment methods" sections from magento onepage checkout. I just want to take in user shipping details and nothing more. I followed this [article](http://nightlyworker.posterous.com/magento-skip-shipping-and-payment-method-step) as a starting point.

I made the required changes in `OnepageController.php` and `opcheckout.js`(as i am using zero subtotal checkout payment method, i replaced "paypal_express" with "free" in the code from the article.)

Now in the front end in the checkout page, after clicking the place order button (last step of checkout) there is no action performed. i found this error through my console :
malformed URI sequence

```
[Break On This Error] var key = decodeURIComponent(pair.shift());
in file path =>\js\prototype\prototype.js line no:425
```

After a little research, i found that in `opcheckout.js(\skin\frontend\base\default\js\opcheckout.js)` , has a variable `var params = "payment% 5Bmethod% 5D = free";` which is not being decoded in prototype.js , line : `var key = decodeURIComponent(pair.shift());`

Could some one please help me solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no need in ' ' whitespaces.
Working example from one of our projects:

```
//var params = Form.serialize(payment.form);
var params = "payment%5Bmethod%5D=checkmo";
```

Comment: Got rid of the spaces but that dint help. Anything else i could be missing? Thanks.

Comment: Uhm shouldn't it be freeshipping but not free? Also try to insert some alert there or something like this. Perhaps alert will show the reason.

Comment: 'free' is the code for Zero checkout payment method. We are running a rewards store and so no payment is required. Followed a few other articles and was able to skip either the payment or the shipping step but not both.

Comment: Did you tried alert? Because if code is corect than I guess the problem is with controllers.